# Jax2bMarshaller setClassesToBeBound and extra xmlns

Tags: java, xml, jaxb2

I'm using Jaxb2Marshaller and bound multiple classes to it. When I marshal, the object appears to be mapped to xml, but there are multiple xmlns to other objects that were not related to the mapped object. Is there a way to avoid unrelated xmlns from appearing in output, preferably without modifying the base objects?

on Bike Object:

```
@XmlElement(name = "bike", namespace = "http://company.com/bike", required = true)
```

on Bus object

```
@XmlElement(name = "bus", namespace = "http://company.com/bus", required = true)
```

Code

```
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(com.company.bike.class, com.company.bus.class, com.company.car.class);

StringWriter outWriter = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult( outWriter );

Class bike = new Bike();
bike.setBikeType("fast-bike");
marshaller.marshal(bike, result);
```

Result

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns4:bike xsi:schemaLocation="" xmlns:ns2="http://company.com/bike" xmlns:ns4="http://company.com/bus" xmlns:ns1="http://company.com/car" xmlns:ns3="http://company.com/bike-type">
    <ns3:bike-type>
      fast-bike
    </ns3:bike-type>
</ns4:bike>
```

Comment: is it just a mater of aesthetic? defining namespaces and not using them is not a problem.

Comment: Assuming the receiving endpoint checks the namespace which object to map to, or has a known class to explicitly map to, yes it appears to be aesthetic. Thanks.